# Qt QStandardItem setCheckable(true) dosn’t save checkbox state

Tags: c++, qt

i have simple QStandardItemModel that holds the date to show in QTreeview
when i set one off the columns with :

```
   items.insert(1,new QStandardItem());
    items.at(1)->setCheckable(true);
    m_model->insertRow(0,items);
```

then i check the checkbox , and close the QDialog that holds the Qtreeview .
when i open the QDialog box again the state dosn’t saved . i dont build it again , all the other columns that are text
are saved in the view .
what im doing wrong , i dont what to loop and save the states over and over .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'setCheckable(true);' just enable the widget to have be checkable. If you do `setChecked(true);` after, your widget will be checked.